# javafx : mark some pagination control number

Tags: javafx, pagination

Is it possible to mark some **pagination** control **button** to indicate a page contains something important?
example: change the background color of the button 5 and 7
thank's a lot.

Comment: thx,  <!-- language: java -->public void colorImportantIndicatorButton(Parent node) {
  int i = 0;
  
  for (Node subNode : node.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
   
   if (subNode.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("IndicatorButton")) {
    subNode.setId("IB" + i);

    if ( isImportant(i) ) {
     subNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
    }
    i++;
   }

   if (subNode instanceof Parent) {
    traverse((Parent) subNode);
   }
  }

}


public boolean isImportant(int index){
 // return true or false
}

Comment: Is this the answer or is it supposed to be apart of the question?

Comment: thx,  it's a solution

Comment: If you want to answer your own question and post a solution, do it in the `Your Answer` section and not the `Comment` section.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void colorImportantIndicatorButton(Parent node) {
    int i = 0;
     for (Node subNode : node.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
       if (subNode.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("IndicatorButton")) {
          subNode.setId("IB" + i); 
          if ( isImportant(i) ) { 
            subNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;"); 
          } 
         i++;
        } 

        if (subNode instanceof Parent) {
           colorImportantIndicatorButton((Parent) subNode); 
        } 
      } 
    } 

    public boolean isImportant(int index){ // return true or false }
```